# Why do I have to use a two-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, c-strings, pointer-arithmetic

I'm reviewing this code which converts the capital letters to lower case and I don't understand why it declares `char*argv[]` and later inside the for loop it uses `argv[1][i]` as if it were a two-dimensional array.
Any tip is welcomed, thanks.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    if(argc>1) {
        int i;
        char c;
        for(i=1; (c=argv[1][i]) != '\0'; i++){
            if('A'<=c && c<='Z')
                putchar(c+'a'-'A');
            else
                putchar(c);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not strictly a 2D array, but a "jagged array". The `argv[]` is an array of pointers, which themselves can be indexed. The point of a jagged array is that each row can be a different length/size.

Comment: In C, arrays implictly decay into pointers. Remember that `v[i]` means the same as `*(v + i)`: you're allowed to use pointers as if they were arrays, and you're allowed to pass arrays to functions which were expecting pointers for the same reason.

Comment: You might like section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/), and possibly many other sections too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argv` is not actually a 2 dimensional array but an array of `char *`.  Each of those pointers point to a string, each of which is a `char` array, so it can be accessed the same way a 2 dimensional array is.

More specifically, each member of `argv` is a command line argument passed to the program, with the first member conventionally being the name of the program.  Those arguments are strings, and each string is an array of characters.  So `argv[1][i]` grabs the *i*th character from the first command line argument.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, I finally understood it.

Answer (score 0):

As it is seen from the declaration of the second parameter in main

```
char*argv[]
```

it is an array of pointers of the type `char *`.

Pay attention to that function parameters having array types are adjusted by the compiler to pointers to array element types.

So these two declarations of main

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char**argv){
```

are equivalent.

So if you have an array of pointers like for example

```
char * s[] = { "Hello", "World" };
```

then this array contains two pointers to first characters of the string literals `"Hello"` and `"World"`.

So to output elements of the array you can use these nested for loops

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ) /* == 2 */; ++i )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; s[i][j] != '\0'; ++j )
    {
        putchar( s[i][j] );
    }
    putchar( ' ' );
}

putchar( '\n' );
```

To understand the inner loop consider the following code snippet

```
char *p = "Hello";
for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
{
    [utchar( s[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

In the first code snippet you have an array of two such pointers.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code with parameters, they are stored in the **char argv** array.
This means that the values are stored in a char array (holding a string value)

Each parameter is separated with spaces e.g. **a.exe hello**.
If you do `printf("%s", argv[1]);`
You will get the result "hello", the value of `argv[1]`  is the whole string, if you want to access individual characters of that string you can do it by using multi-array notation `argv[1][0]` which will give you the first char, in this case, **h**